# Create a pdf with dimensions 1700pixels*2200pixels in java using pdfBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have an application which opens a pdf file with dimensions 1700pixels*2200pixels. I will get dimensions of a rectangle drawn over a pdf from it. 
When I am trying to create the same rectangle on a pdf, 
I am using PdfBox which creates a pdf page with dimensions.

```
System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getHeight());
System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getWidth());
```

results in :

```
612 
792
```

How to convert the pdf coordinates from 1700*2200 to 612*792?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your output

```
612 792
```

of

```
System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getHeight()); System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getWidth());
```

seems to indicate that you create that `PDPage` using the default constructor, i.e. using `new PDPage()` as that constructor sets the page size to the US Letter page format.

If you want pages in a different format, you should use the constructor `PDPage(PDRectangle)`, e.g.:

```
    PDRectangle rec = new PDRectangle(1700, 2200);
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(rec);
    document.addPage(page);
```

This creates a PDF with a page whose size is 1700x2200 user space units, i.e. about 23.6"x30.6".

BTW, you talk about **a pdf file in the dimensions 1700pixels*2200pixels** - PDFs don't know the unit 'pixel'. They know the default user space unit which defaults to 1/72" and, therefore, more or less corresponds to the unit point. This especially does not imply a resolution.

Comment: I am using PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDPage page = (PDPage)document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNo); How to give dimensions here ? BTW my Pdf opens in an application in 1700 * 2200 dimensions , but it is not actually of that size.I will actually get a rectangle dimensions drawn in that application which i needs to create of my own . so I want to create a pdf of that size and draw the rectangle.

Comment: You wrote that *PDFBox created that page* and asked how to *create a pdf with dimensions...*. The code you now show **does not create** a new page but merely retrieves an existing page. So you seem to contradict yourself; please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry , I will retrive a page from a pdf . Can u pls tell what are the better API`s to do the above requirement. Thanks.

Comment: *I will retrive a page from a pdf* - ok. And what actually do you want to do? Do you want to increase the page size to 1700 * 2200? Or do you merely want to transform the coordinate system so that follow-up code can assume a (distorted) 1700 * 2200 coordinate system?

Comment: The Application has a pdf shown in 1700 * 2200 . I will get the coordinates from that application and when i am trying to create pdf using pdfbox the coordinates are 612 *792 . So , here i want to convert those coordinates(1700*2200) obtained from application to pdfbox created coordinates(612*792). I will get rectangle coordinates , so i tried like doing  1700/2.78 = 612 & 2200/2.78 = 792 .The new  x, y ,w, h  are obtained , but there is a variation in y coordinate location . I want to resolve this . Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that the origin of the coordinate system in PDFs can be anywhere and very often is in the lower left corner of the page while some applications prefer coordinates with the origin in the upper left, aren't you? Thus you probably do not merely have to calculate *y' = y/2.78* but instead something like *y' = 792 - y/2.78*.

Comment: I am not aware of it . I am just a beginner . I tried with the above value of y` but i am not getting it correctly. The top corner of rectangle is drawn at place of bottom corner.I mean to say that the rectangle is drawn at same location but it is shifted to 180 degrees upwards. Please suggest .[Link]http://tinypic.com/r/zkij69/8

Comment: As an Addendum to my last comment, PDF y-coordinates usually increase in the upwards direction while image y-coordinates often increase in the downward direction. You seem to have the correct starting point but have not considered this directional stuff. For a more detailled suggestion, the pivotal code and some example input data are needed.

Comment: Please check the screenshot which i have shared in my previous comment. The left one is the original and right side one is the generated pdf . the coordinates for the rectangle in the screenshot are X = 598|Y = 177|WIDTH = 587|HEIGHT = 263|

Comment: So you should draw a rectangle with a diagonal from [598/2.78, 792 - 177/2.78] to [(598+587)/2.78, 792 - (177+263)/2.78].

Comment: Finally I got it . Thank You very much and the new formula for y` is y` = (792-(y/2.78)-h); You made me to complete my task by giving the idea y`=792-(y/2.78). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem of pdf like that my one page is of 810.0 height ,630.0 weight and another is of 3769.92 height,2060.4 weight so when I am converting pdf into image my first page is showning and on second page it is giving fail so what should I do